# How to install softwares for all users?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04 server among a small group. How can I install some common software that all users can use at the same time?

On my own laptop, I can just use `apt-get`. However, it has a huge limitation. For some package, it requires `sudo` to fully function. For example, when `tmux` is installed by `apt-get`, it requires `sudo` to properly load `.tmux.conf`. Without `sudo`, `tmux` starup takes forever.

what is the best practice here?

Comment: apt-get install should always be prefaced by `sudo`, failure to do so will result in potentially incomplete installations. Whenever software is installed with apt tools, it should be installed for all users by default. Instead of using the old apt get commands, just do it directly with apt (apt install instead of apt-get install), if the system is configured properly it should automatically call it as root (sudo) and prompt for the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install software in Ubuntu using apt-get, it is installed system-wide for every user. However in nearly all cases, it is required to be root to do so.
One way to become root -if you are not yet- is to prepend commands with sudo. This applies to all packages to be installed using apt-get.

The problem, that you require root to start tmux is probably a different problem, unrelated to the package installation via apt-get.
Maybe this could help you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/405391/tmux-wont-run-as-non-root-user

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at how linux's directory structure is constructed .  For example, [this link](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained/)

Non-essential binaries for multi-user use can typically be placed in /usr, /usr/bin, or /usr/local/bin.  This link here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/usr-bin-vs-usr-local-bin-on-linux goes into greater detail.

Obviously package managers may put their apps elsewhere, but that is the historical purpose for these directories.